# How to take information that takes entered into a entry box and save(dump) it in a text file(json)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I created a program which should dump the username and password in json file

But i am having problem in solving it

plz help

```
def createAccount():
    A = tk.StringVar()
    B = tk.StringVar()
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.resizable(0, 0)
    root1.title('Signup')
    instruction = Label(root1, text='Please Enter new Credentials')
    instruction.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

    nameL = Label(root1, text='New Username: ')
    pwordL = Label(root1, text='New Password: ')
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    pwordL.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    nameE = Entry(root1, textvariable=A)
    pwordE = Entry(root1, textvariable=B )
    nameE.grid(row=1, column=1)
    pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1)

    signupButton = Button(root1, text='Signup')
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    root1.mainloop()
    username = A
    password = B
    with open('user_accounts.json', 'r+') as user_accounts:
        users = json.load(user_accounts)
        if username in users.keys():
            print('error')

        else:
                users[username] = [password, "PLAYER"]
                user_accounts.seek(0)
                json.dump(users, user_accounts)
                user_accounts.truncate()
                print("success")
```

I tried to convert username and password into string by using tk.StringVar()

But a error is displayed
[image]

Plz provide any appropriate solution

Comment: That error is because you're trying to use the `StringVar`s themselves, rather than calling `.get()` on them to retrieve their contents.  But you have a more fundamental problem here - you're doing this *immediately* after creating the widgets, there is no possibility that the user has entered anything yet, in fact the widgets aren't even visible on the screen at that point.  You need to do everything that requires user input later, typically in a function specified as the `command=` option of a Button.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste and format it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter labels don't use normal Python variables types. Instead, they use tcl types, such as `StringVar`. to get the values of such variables, you can call their `.get()` method, which returns a native Python value. Now you can convert, change and use it as you like :)

Comment: it creates a blank username and password which is added in the json file.... Whats the solution to that

Comment: Hard to tell since I can't see the code nor the error... Could you please share the full code and elaborate on the failure?

Comment: To be clear, did you assign this way: `username = A.get()`, `password = B.get()`? or did you call `.get()` somewhere else? @Bhaskarpal

Comment: small nitpick: the `.get()` method doesn't return a variable, it returns a native value such as a string or integer.

Comment: @pitamer I got my solution my doing few changes thnx a lot